# How to use AppenderSkeleton, Logger and LoggingEvent in Log4j_2.x

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am new to using log4j. My current task involves migrating log4j 1.2 to log4j 2.6. We use slf4j version 2.x of log4j. I have updated jar files to required versions.
I am getting following error in finding symbols AppenderSkeleton, Logger and LoggingEvent. 
How can I use these classes in log4j 2.x or is there any alternative if these classes are deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your current usage: have you customized Log4j 1 components, or is your application simply calling the Log4j 1 library?

If no customization you can continue to use the SLF4J API or even the Log4j 1 API (using the log4j-1.2-api module).

If you have custom Log4j 1 components you need to take a closer look. It's possible that the desired behavior has been implemented in Log4j 2 so the customization is no longer required. If you do still need it, then I would not extend Logger or LogEvent. Extend AbstractAppender if you want to create a custom appender.

Let the Log4j community know of your requirements so they can steer you in the right direction.

Comment: Application is calling the Log4j 1 library for testing purpose.

Comment: I found this [link] (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html.)
I am new to system and they are calling `Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(appender)` and `Logger.getRootLogger().removeAppender(appender)` . I am not sure how to upgrade that with Log4j 2.6.

Comment: Document instructs to remove `Appender`s methods. Can you please tell me how can I remove `Appender` method attached to getRootLogger(). If I simply remove it, will it affect Loggers?
Thanks.